# Too many argument in invocation of macro

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor

When I define the below macro, code compiles fine:

```
 #define RSC_HWIO_INXFI(client,drvID,reg,index,field)    HWIO_INXFI((APCS_RSCC_RSCC_RSC_REG_BASE+RSC_DRV_OFFSET(drvID)), APCS_RSCC_##reg,index,field)
```

But when I include conditional operator to include more clients/targets then I get the error "Too many argument in invocation of macro"

```
#define RSC_HWIO_INXFI(client,drvID,reg,index,field)    \
                    (APCS_RSCC         == client ? HWIO_INXFI((APCS_RSCC_RSCC_RSC_REG_BASE+RSC_DRV_OFFSET(drvID)), APCS_RSCC_##reg,index,field) : \
                    (MSS_RSCC          == client ? HWIO_INXFI((MSS_RSCC_RSCC_RSC_REG_BASE+RSC_DRV_OFFSET(drvID)), MSS_RSCC_##reg,index,field) : \
                    (MSS_QDSP6SS_RSCC  == client ? HWIO_INXFI((MSS_QDSP6SS_RSCC_RSCC_RSC_REG_BASE+RSC_DRV_OFFSET(drvID)), MSS_QDSP6SS_RSCC_##reg,index,field) : \
                    (AOP_RSCC          == client ? HWIO_INXFI((AOP_RSCC_RSCC_RSC_REG_BASE+RSC_DRV_OFFSET(drvID)), AOP_RSCC_##reg,index,field) : HWIO_INXFI((APCS_RSCC_RSCC_RSC_REG_BASE+RSC_DRV_OFFSET(drvID)), APCS_RSCC_##reg,index,field)))))
```

Point to be noted the error is coming only for the last 3 clients i.e. MSS_RSCC, MSS_QDSP6SS_RSCC & AOP_RSCC. Not for the first one (APCS_RSCC)

Any clue?

Regards,

Comment: First of all, please don't tag multiple languages, only use the tag for the language you're actually programming in. Secondly, please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which includes all relevant macros and how you use the macro you show us. Lastly, please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error into the question body, including possible informational notes.

Comment: Looks as if you would have got away easier with: `HWIO_INXFI((client##_RSCC_RSC_REG_BASE+RSC_DRV_OFFSET(drvID)), client##_##reg,index,field)`...

Comment: XYZ_RSCC are pointers? If not, be aware that the pre-processor does **not** resolve comparisons, so if XYZ_RSCC does not exist as a symbol itself, `XYZ_RSCC == client` will fail to compile afterwards!

Comment: @Aconcagua why would you need pointers for that? It would also work with macros, enums or other identifier.

Comment: @Aconcagua I am getting this error:  Error:  #20: identifier "client_RSCC_RSC_REG_BASE" is undefined when I tried this: #define RSC_HWIO_INXFI(client,drvID,reg,index,field)    HWIO_INXFI((client##_RSCC_RSC_REG_BASE+RSC_DRV_OFFSET(drvID)), client##_##reg,index,field)

Comment: Compiles as it is on my machine (LLVM). Are there any other definitions?
HWIO_INXFI() - is it another macro?

Comment: Which parameters do you provide when you use that macro? What type do they have? Please provide a MCVE as mentioned above.

Comment: Horrible macro , error prone, not debuggable. You should use the inline function instead.

Comment: The way the cpp works, each of your client, `drvID`, `index`, `field` arguments are evaluated and plugged into your macro first. Then, your `reg` argument is pasted. _Then_, everything remaining is evaluated (during rescan-and-replacement) as if it appeared separately. I hope that helps, because otherwise it's impossible to help you... you have not provided a MCVE (see above); you just complained about something not working with >200-characters-per-line macros, no invocation, and your own opinion as to where something's failing. (repost-edited)

Comment: @Gerhardh Well, you are right in fact - pointers only are a very common way to represent registers - or sets of registers, that's why I came to... The important point is, though, that `client` needs to resolve to some valid ***C*** identifier because of the already mentioned limited functionality of the preprocessor...

Comment: @user3565150 Strange - if `APCS_RSCC_##reg` worked fine in the original macro, why shouldn't it then, too, with the other one??? Does not matter, you can have an intermediate concatenation macro. Will write an answer for, as comments are too short...

Answer (score 0):

You intoduced comparisons within your macro:

```
APCS_RSCC == client
```

This will only work, if `APCS_RSCC` itself is a valid ***C*** identifier. The preprocessor does not resolve comparisons like these, but leaves them to the compiler. APCS_RSCC then *could* be another macro that resolves to some kind of pointer (e. g. to a struct containing several addresses), or simply some bare  address (`APCS_RSCC_RSCC_RSC_REG_BASE` then might resolve to something like `(APCS_RSCC->RSCC_RSC_REG_BASE)` or `(APCS_RSCC + RSCC_RSC_REG_BASE)`. The naming, though, does not give me the impression of such definitions...

Concatenation now would be the way to go:

```
#define RSC_HWIO_INXFI(client,drvID,reg,index,field)       \
HWIO_INXFI(                                                \
    client##_RSCC_RSC_REG_BASE + RSC_DRV_OFFSET(drvID),    \
    client##_##reg,index,field                             \
)                                                          \
```

OK, now you told me in the comments that this macro did not compile. Provided that the original macro worked, strange, as you concatenated at the same level there:

```
#define RSC_HWIO_INXFI(client,drvID,reg,index,field)       \
HWIO_INXFI(                                                \
    (APCS_RSCC_RSCC_RSC_REG_BASE + RSC_DRV_OFFSET(drvID)), \
    APCS_RSCC_##reg, index, field                          \
)
//            ^^
```

You can circumvent the problem via indirection of the concatenation (analogously to stringification, have you met these macros already?):

```
#define RSC_HWIO_INXFI(client, drvID, reg, index, field)           \
HWIO_INXFI(                                                        \
    CONCAT3(client, _, RSCC_RSC_REG_BASE) + RSC_DRV_OFFSET(drvID), \
    CONCAT3(client, _, reg), index, field                          \
)
#define CONCAT3(X, Y, Z) X##Y##Z
```